# What's happening when gdb sets multiple breakpoints on the same symbol at different addresses?

Tags: c++, gdb

What's happening when I set my breakpoint on a symbol like: `b Lock::acquire`, but gdb shows multiple address for the same symbol?

```
1.1                         y     0x000000000184b1df in Lock::acquire(bool) at lock.cpp:332
1.2                         y     0x00007fa92b96099f in Lock::acquire(bool) at lock.cpp:332
1.3                         y     0x00007fa95ca35da1 in Lock::acquire(bool) at lock.cpp:332
1.4                         y     0x00007fab4ef7b8b3 in Lock::acquire(bool) at lock.cpp:332
1.5                         y     0x00007facd672e94b in Lock::acquire(bool) at lock.cpp:332
```

My expectation that one symbol always refers one address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inlined functions can appear inside other functions, at various addresses.

Comment: That makes sense - I don't see the `inline` keyword in the function declaration though.  Could there be another explanation?

Comment: @Joe: `inline` used to be hint. The keyword was added decades ago, when compilers weren't so good. Modern compilers do quite well without hints. `inline` currently has a slightly different meaning, "can be defined more than once - let the linker deal with that".

Comment: Thanks, @MSalters - very much appreciate your clear and concise answer.